# Hibernate Search 6 returning result but explanation value is 0.0

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, hibernate-search

I'm experimenting with hibernate search 6 since 5 was a lot harder to use for me.

But when the explanation's for the match is 0.0 the entity is still returned as a result ?

And why does 0.0 is sometimes this

```java
2020-09-15 21:57:43.107  INFO 18032 --- [nio-8080-exec-8] n.l.a.s.r.search.HibernateSearchService  : 0.0 = Failure to meet condition(s) of required/prohibited clause(s)
  0.0 = no match on required clause ((MatchNoDocsQuery("empty BooleanQuery"))^4.0 description:amonsdu platform:amonsdu platformId:amonsdu)
    0.0 = No matching clauses
  0.0 = match on required clause, product of:
    0.0 = # clause
    1.0 = __HSEARCH_type:main
```

=> not returned as result

and sometimes this ?

```java
2020-09-15 21:57:46.475  INFO 18032 --- [io-8080-exec-10] n.l.a.s.r.search.HibernateSearchService  : 0.0 = sum of:
  0.0 = sum of:
    0.0 = ConstantScore(name:us)^0.0
  0.0 = match on required clause, product of:
    0.0 = # clause
    1.0 = __HSEARCH_type:main
```

=> returned as result

here's the code that handles the search

```java
@Transactional
    public Page<Game> fuzzySearch(String searchTerm, Pageable pageable) {
        SearchSession searchSession = Search.session(entityManager);
        LuceneSearchQuery<Game> gameSearchQuery = searchSession.search(Game.class)
                .extension(LuceneExtension.get())
                .where(f -> f.bool()
                        .should(
                                f.match()
                                        .field("name")
                                        .matching(searchTerm)
                                        .fuzzy(2, 0)
                                        .boost(4)
                        ).should(
                                f.phrase()
                                        .field("description")
                                        .matching(searchTerm)
                                        .slop(3)
                                        .boost(1)
                        )
                        .should(
                                f.match()
                                        .fields("platform", "platformId")
                                        .matching(searchTerm)
                        )

                ).toQuery();
        SearchResult<Game> result = gameSearchQuery.fetch((int) pageable.getOffset(), pageable.getPageSize());
        Explanation explanation = gameSearchQuery.explain(21L);
        log.info(explanation.toString());
        log.info(result.hits().toString());
        return new PageImpl<>(result.hits(), pageable, result.total().hitCount());
    }
```

The entity that is being searched

```java
@Data
@MappedSuperclass
public class GameInfo {

    @FullTextField(analyzer = "gameName")
    @NotBlank
    @Size(min = 2, max = 500)
    private String name;

    @FullTextField(analyzer = "gameDescription")
    @Size(max = 6000)
    private String description;

    @KeywordField
    private String platform;

    @KeywordField
    private String platformId;


}
```

And the custom analyzers

```java
 public void configure(LuceneAnalysisConfigurationContext context) {
            context.analyzer("gameName").custom()
                    .tokenizer(WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.class)
                    .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class);
            context.analyzer("gameDescription").custom()
                    .tokenizer(StandardTokenizerFactory.class)
                    .tokenFilter(LowerCaseFilterFactory.class)
                    .tokenFilter(SnowballPorterFilterFactory.class)
                        .param("language","English");
    }
```

Comment: This looks odd, but I was unable to reproduce this behavior. What's the value of the various properties for the `Game` instance that matched? Could you adjust [this project](https://github.com/yrodiere/hibernate-test-case-templates/tree/stackoverflow-matches-0score/search/hibernate-search-6/orm-lucene) to reproduce the problem?

Comment: I got it to reproduce here : https://github.com/LelouBil/hibernate-search-test
I matches on any 2 letter query i think because the "us" keyword will always have maximum 2 edit distance from any other 2 letter query so the fact that it matches is not a bug i think. However I think the explanation is still wrong, but it comes from lucene , not hibernate search right ?

Comment: It looks like there's a spoiler in there... I do not thank you :) Regarding your problem... Yes, that's probably why it matches. And indeed, Hibernate Search only forwards the explanation from Lucene.

Comment: @yrodiere do you have any idea how/where I could report this for lucene ?

Comment: @LelouBill I'm not entirely convinced it's a bug, that could be intentional. Better bring this to a mailing list first: https://lucene.apache.org/core/discussion.html . If they want  Lucene code, I'm not sure this will be very helpful, but here you go: https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/00f9ff67a92a204a27809f3ddf82f738548afcac/backend/lucene/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/backend/lucene/lowlevel/query/impl/FuzzyQueryBuilder.java#L30